# Undefined variable on missing controller pages

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

If I go to a destination on my site which doesn't have a defined controller, I get the normal Missing Controller error message rendered within my layout, however, one of my variables which I'm calling in my beforeFilter() function inside of my app_controller, is undefined.

```
public function beforeFilter() {

    $totalSubmissions = $this->Submission->find('count');
}
```

Then, I've got an element (e.g. sidebar_count.ctp) which calls that $totalSubmissions value. It works on all other pages, aside from this. Is there a way I can get it to ALWAYS render that value?

The response I get in place of that count is:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: totalSubmissions [APP/views/elements/sidebar_count.ctp, line 7]
```

Do I need to add something to my app_controller to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to set the variable for view, hence it is not available neither in view, nor in elements you include. Fixing that should make it propagate corerctly to elements.

```
public function beforeFilter() {

    $this->set('totalSubmissions', $this->Submission->find('count'));
}
```

Comment: Good catch. I actually do this, but it still gives me the error. I just set that count result to a variable and put that in the $this->set.. below, which I failed to mention.

Comment: Does it happen in all elements that you include or just this one?